# Reference to System.net on PCL and MVVMCross

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm builind my PCL Core library using MVVMCross and Mono with VisualStudio 2012 and Stable version of Xamarin.
I have following compile error.

> Error 3   'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When try to do that:

```
string address = "http://www.test.com/;

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;  
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "customcookie");
```

HttpWebRequest  is well referenced.

N.B. Same code work in Xamarin Studio on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PCL `System.Net` stack is **portable** - which means it isn't fully featured.

For cookies in the PCL .Net stack I believe you can set the `CookieCollection` on a `Request` and that you can then inspect the `Cookies` on a `Response`

If that's not sufficient for you, then you'll have to use some kind of 'injection' technique to implement the functionality you want on each platform - e.g. you could use [plugins in mvvmcross](https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/plugins-in-mvvmcross)

---

I think one thing that you may be missing is that currently xamarin does not build PCLs correctly - this is about to change, but right now today xamarin builds PCLs against its full monotouch or monodroid stack. As a result, xamarin may report pcl functionality availability incorrectly - and PCLs built on xamarin are certainly not portable - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/almost-portable-binaries.html

Comment: it's an embedded cookie on my request. I don't read from a response...I've tried do to some thing with Network plugin in MVVMCross but didn't work...Same code on Xamarin Studio on Mac works fine linking system.net library...

Comment: As Stuart mentioned the portable version of WebHeaderCollection is missing the Add method.  It does have the item[] operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hb8kfxw.aspx) so you can use this instead.  Usually when a member is missing from PCL it is because it isn't supported by one of the profiles you are targeting.  CookieContainer works as well.

Comment: Could you explain me way same code works on Mac with Xamarin? For sure Profile are different but library must be the same...

Comment: Please try asking a full question. I don't understand what you mean at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have latest mvvmcross and Xamarin. When I try to set request.CookieContainer I get an exception.
Described in [Xamarin bugzilla here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15046) and [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11307)