# MvvmCross Plugin Network and Cookie

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm tring to make a rest request that require an embedded cookie. I've do that using System.Net reference in that way

[Reference to System.net on PCL and MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742172/reference-to-system-net-on-pcl-and-mvvmcross)

but i've problem to port that PCL library (System.Net) on VS2012. That code infact works fine on Xamarin Studio on Mac.

Referred to that question i've tried to use Network Plugin of MVVMCross in that way:

```
var url = "http://api.myaddress.com/api";
var json = new Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.MvxJsonConverter();
var client = new Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxJsonRestClient
{
JsonConverterProvider = () => json
};
var request = new MvxRestRequest(url);
MvxDecodedRestResponse<SearchItem> theResponse = null;
    Exception exception = null;
CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection ();
cc.Add(new Cookie("mycookiename","mycookievalue","/","api.myaddress.com"));

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

request.CookieContainer.Add(cc);
client.MakeRequestFor<SearchItem>(request,
                                                    (result) => { theResponse = result; },
                                                (error) => { exception = error; });
```

I've this error "The requested feature is not implemented."

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.get_SupportsCookieContainer () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:553 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.HttpWebRequest:get_SupportsCookieContainer ()
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxRestClient.SetCookieContainer (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxRestRequest restRequest, System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpRequest) [0x00000] in /Users/stuartlodge/Documents/GitHub/Mvx/MvvmCross/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network/Rest/MvxRestClient.cs:128 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxRestClient.BuildHttpRequest (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxRestRequest restRequest) [0x00028] in /Users/stuartlodge/Documents/GitHub/Mvx/MvvmCross/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network/Rest/MvxRestClient.cs:100 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxRestClient+c__AnonStorey2.<>m__4 () [0x0000d] in /Users/stuartlodge/Documents/GitHub/Mvx/MvvmCross/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network/Rest/MvxRestClient.cs:60 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxRestClient.TryCatch (System.Action toTry, System.Action`1 errorAction) [0x00000] in /Users/stuartlodge/Documents/GitHub/Mvx/MvvmCross/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network/Rest/MvxRestClient.cs:20

That is the code that works on Mac and that i'd like to port using MvvMCross Network Plugin

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.myaddress.com/api") as HttpWebRequest;  
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "mycookievalue");

        // Get response  

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) {  
            // Get the response stream  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream());  
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }

        SearchItem itemssr = jsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchItem>(content);
```

Comment: One side issue - calling `var client = new Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Rest.MvxJsonRestClient` is not portable - use IoC instead - e.g. `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxJsonRestClient>()` - that way you can get a different implementation on different platforms if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

That particular part of the Network plugin is currently under development - see [GitHub Issue for REST plugin](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/240)

It looks as though the cookie feature isn't going to work on the platform you are testing (which I guess from the stacktrace is xamarin.ios)

In this one case, this might be down to temporary issues in Xamarin.iOS - see:

- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/14628/#Comment_14628

---

More generally for Plugin development, where a feature doesn't work, then whoever is writing the plugin will have to either override that functionality on that particular platform or will have to mark that feature is NotImplemented on that platform.

Note that marking features as not implemented is perfectly normal - there are always somethings that will not be implemented on some platforms.

Assuming the feature can be implemented then whoever is contributing to the network plugin might:

- implement an MvxTouchJsonRestClient somewhere in: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Touch

  - this implementation would inherit from the PCL core
  - this implementation would have to override SetCookieContainer somehow - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network/Rest/MvxRestClient.cs#L126
- this implementation would then be registered with IoC for Touch in the Plugin.cs file - in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Touch/Plugin.cs#L21

If this isn't a temporary Xamarin.iOS issue, then I expect that someone will add cookie support in this way at some point soon. If you want that support sooner, then:

- ask on the GitHub issue, giving the contributors a use case (someone might prioritise it)
- contribute the code yourself

If working with this existing Network plugin is too large an initial leap, then maybe start by looking at a simpler plugin - see the much simpler Vibrate example in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/plugins-in-mvvmcross

---

If you don't want to mess around with plugins, then just find some other way of moving forwards - e.g. using your own native non-PCL library for that part of the functionality.

---

**Side note:**

> That code infact works fine on Xamarin Studio on Mac.

As I tried to explain in the other question, currently XS has 'fake' PCL support - so PCLs built in XS are just normal assemblies and are **not** portable.